# com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID remove from a released play console app but detected when I try to declare no ad's on play console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

First I had an app validated with ad's, data information on playstore declare ad's

Second I have remove ad's cause of bad match rate, so I remove all trace of admob Ad_ID, package etc ... I upgrade my app on playstore without change data privacy.

After app is validated I try to change data privacy to remove ad's information.

Problem ... I have this error

```
Unable to send updates because some information about your app is incomplete
You must resolve the following issues before submitting your updates for review:
This version includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission, but your declaration in Play Console indicates that your app does not use the advertising ID.

You must update your advertising identifier declaration.
```

But I have no trace au com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID on the manifest, no package extern, just a basic game free.

Playstore force me to lie about ad's. I launch some message to playstore team

here is the response

```
Thank you for contacting Google Play Developer Support.   

As part of Google Play services update in late 2021, the advertising ID will be removed when a user opts out of personalization using advertising ID in Android Settings. 

Please note that this Google Play services phased rollout will affect apps running on Android 12 starting late 2021 and will expand to affect apps running on all devices that support Google Play starting April 1, 2022. For essential non ads use-cases such as analytics and fraud prevention, use App Set ID.     

If your current release doesn't have this permission, you are still required to submit this form because our system detected that your app was using this permission in your existing release. You can just fill out the form and inform the review team that you do not have any permissions in your current release.    

Also, to deactivate the current APK, you need to release a new compliant app bundle or APK on the same track where the non-compliant version is located in order for the non-compliant APK to be deactivated. The new release will then supersede or overwrite the non-compliant APK on your app.   

In this case, please update your Sensitive permissions and APIs in your App Content section. After that, please try to release your new versions to their specific track. Please also note that you won’t be able to release a new update unless you fill out the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission form.    

If your app update is still rejected after the new release, please contact the Policy team for further clarification regarding your app’s policy violation.    

This permission will be enforced starting from April 1, 2022 for all devices. See API documentation for more details.

You can refer to this help center for more information about the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permissions.    

I hope this information helps. Please let me know if you have any other questions or clarifications - I'd be happy to help.

Regards,
Red 
Google Play Developer Support
```

I don't understant, what I need to do. The only solution I see is to create a new app or lie about ad's and let wrong information on the playstore page of my app...